# Get the values of all select options on change event javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to know all the values of a select element once the change event is recorded on it.

Code is like this:

**PHP**

```
<select name='variant' class='variantsselect' onchange='on(this.value)'>
  <option value='a'>a</option>
  <option value='a'>a</option>
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function on(value){
    alert(value); //This gives me selected value
};
```

I need values `a` & `b` when change event is recorded on select element. Can someone help?

Comment: Why do you need to know all the options? It doesn't seem like the options change.

Comment: Reason is I need to hide one element & show the other and for that I gotta know the old & new value (all values to say).

Comment: Are you using the option value to get the element id you want to hide/show? for example: `<option value="cars">Something</option>` and use the value cars to hide/show another element using `id="cars"` ? I'm just curious on your method to hide/show before I decide on posting an answer.

Comment: Yes, on the basis of the value I get, I show that div & hides the old one

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name='variant' class='variantsselect' onchange="javascript:valueselect(this)">

function valueselect(sel) {
      var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
      alert(value)
   }
```

**EDIT:**

```
<select name='variant' id='variant' class='variantsselect' onchange="javascript:displayResult()">

function displayResult() {
  var x = document.getElementById("variant");
  var i;
  var txt = "Text: ";

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    txt = txt + "\n" + x.options[i].text;
  }

 alert(txt);

}
```

Comment: This gives me selected value only

Comment: @Shanil Soni did u try it?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the last selected value in a variable and overwrite the variable with the new selected value at the end of your function. When the function is called the variable will = to the last option selected *(If you don't set a default value the variable will be empty on the first call)*

[**Click Here For Demo**](http://jsbin.com/hefanuwufe/1/edit?html,js,output)

**OR**

This will work for a simple hide/show select without having to remember the previous selection.

The hide/show content have a class name of HideShow, this class name css display is set to none. When you change the option it will loop through all elements using the class name HideShow to compare the selected value with the id of the element, if they match it will set the style display to block }else{ set style display to none.

> **Demo**
>
> ```js
> function HideShow(Selection){
> var HScontent=document.getElementsByClassName('HideShow');
> for(var i=0; i<HScontent.length; i++){
>     if(HScontent[i].id==Selection){
>         HScontent[i].style.display="block";
>     }else{
>         HScontent[i].style.display="none";
>     }
> }
> }
> ```
>
> ```css
> .HideShow{display:none;}
> ```
>
> ```html
> <select onchange="HideShow(this.value);">
> <option value="cars">Cars</option>
> <option value="bikes">Bikes</option>
> <option value="buses">Buses</option>
> </select>
> <div id="cars" class="HideShow">Cars content.....</div>
> <div id="bikes" class="HideShow">Bikes content....</div>
> <div id="buses" class="HideShow">Buses content....</div>
> ```

If you don't understand something in the demo, leave a comment below and I will try get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!